# How can we convert pdf to images in same resolution?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I have two pdf of different formats, I need to convert those into video both are working with different script, I want any common script for all. any suggestion will be appreciated.

one pdf converting with below script

```
exec("convert -density 150 -quality 100 -resize 800x $pdf_path $temp_images ");
exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 0.5 -b 1800 -i $temp_images_wildcard -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y $frame_target 2>&1",$output);
```

another converting working with this script

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 $pdf_path $temp_images ");
exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 0.5 -b 1800 -i $temp_images_wildcard -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y $frame_target 2>&1",$output);
```

Thanks
Preet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be work :

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 300x300 -quality 100 -resize 1500x $pdf_path $temp_images 2>&1",$output);
exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 0.5 -b 1800 -i $temp_images_wildcard -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y $frame_target 2>&1",$output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
exec("convert -density 200 $pdf_path -resize 800x -quality 100 $temp_images ");
```

Comment: Not helpful! still showing below error: Thanks

**Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height**

Comment: You did not say anything about an error and that looks like an ffmpeg error. How about adding that tag to your question as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer :

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 300x300 -quality 100 -resize 1500x $pdf_path $temp_images 2>&1",$output);
exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -r 0.5 -b 1800 -i $temp_images_wildcard -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y $frame_target 2>&1",$output);
```

Thanks